# How do I say "damn!" or "bloody hell" in Chinese?

Tags: culture, politeness, swearing

The phrase 他妈的 has been explained in [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/150/how-offensive-is-%E4%BB%96%E5%A6%88%E7%9A%84). Since I'm a no-expletives guy, I don't feel comfortable so close to the f-word. :) I was wondering what would be the correct way to use some of the *milder* curse words I use daily like "damn", "bloody hell", "sh*t", "arse" etc.

I'm guessing most of these cannot be translated directly, so I guess what I'm asking is: **What would be more-or-less socially acceptable way of cursing in Chinese when you stub your toe?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May I suggest checking out the [ChinaSmack glossary](http://www.chinasmack.com/glossary)? They have a huge array of colorful language, and there is sure to be something that meets your needs in terms of a curse word there.

Just to add, I always hear Chinese girls saying **讨厌 (taoyan)** when they are annoyed or frustrated, but it's not exactly the most masculine of statements. **烦 (fan)** also seems to be a common expression amongst both genders, although not exactly the meaning you are looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or if stubbing your toe, 哎呀，好疼! might be pretty acceptable. 哎呀is one of my personal favorite words, and probably lines up with what you are trying to express pretty well.

Comment: However, both 讨厌 and 烦 will almost never be used for cursing situations. :P "讨厌" is like "leave me alone" in girly form.

Comment: Yes, 哎呀 or simply "啊(ah..)". ;) But, seems not too many people really say "好疼". It is like written words in novels.

Comment: You definitely may suggest! :) It's amazing how some of these expressions on ChinaSmack are _exactly_ the same as those used in my country. I haven't seen this in any other language (English, German, Italian...)

Comment: Maybe it's the people I hang out with; I have to say, I've heard people say 哎呀 more in the South of China than the North.

Comment: Oh, and glad you like ChinaSmack - the glossary is pretty amazing. There are actually a couple of books on Amazon you may be interested in all about slang and cursing in Chinese - for example http://www.amazon.com/Dirty-Chinese-Everyday-Slang-Whats/dp/1569757275

Comment: @Ciaocibai It may be true, as I come from northern part. 哎呀 seems a little bit girly to me. ;)

Comment: I kind of like 哎呀, it seems quite universal, can be applied in any situation!

Comment: @Flake I just knew you were going to be a Northerner!

Comment: @Ciaocibai ha! Yes I am. Never knew that "哎呀" is commonly used in the South. ;)

Comment: "討厭" is mostly spoken by women. Perhaps "該死" is better.

Answer (score 7):

For cursing:

- "操" is pretty similar to "damn" or "sh*t" in such situation of cursing. Also similar as they should not be used in very formal situations. However, the meaning of "操" is same as the f word in its verb form.
- "操" should be quite acceptable (or at least ok) in informal scenarios.
- "靠" has very very close meaning as "操" in this situation. Actually, it is some thing more dirty in origin.

Just express it hurts e.g. when get a toe stubbed:

- While in very formal situations, I would say "Ah!(啊!)" (same as "Ouch!") without cursing. Note: the ah sound is really short, something short than 1/2 second perhaps.
- 哎呀 has the similar meaning while in my personal impression, 哎呀 is more used in situation of surprises than got hurt.

Comment: Hm, are you sure about 操 being "damn" or "sh*t", my dictionary only says "_to f*ck (vulgar)_"? Doesn't seem like something I'd like to say when my program won't compile!

Comment: By "pretty similar to" I meant only its usage in the situation of cursing. It has real meaning of f word, but in Chinese, widely used for cursing. 靠 is almost the same too. Yes, you can curse using 操 when your program does not compile. But only when you are really annoyed, e.g. when you are close to a deadline or in bad mood.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but being Scottish, 哎呀 is great for me - if I stub my toe or whatever, I already automatically shout 'ai ya!' :)  Well, that or something like 'ai ya f**cker!' :D

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, we have the same thing in Croatian. However, this is exactly the thing I wanted to avoid, I'd like to get a bit more euphemistic if possible. For example, I like using "blast!", "cor blimey!" and other, more "British" expressions so to speak.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter I've never actually heard anyone British say "cor blimey!" in real life, but I take your point :)

Comment: @Cocowalla: I assumed as much, but still..mayhap I've watched too many Fawlty Towers or Jeeves and Wooster episodes...and other "nice" shows... :)

Comment: @drHannibalLecter That is really interesting to know. :D

Comment: @Flake I'm pretty sure 'kao4' (``靠``) is just a [bowdlerization](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bowdlerize) of 'cao4'. Do you have any evidence that it's "more dirty"?

Answer (score 4):

"靠" is more like it, in modern oral Chinese.

While "操" is literally the F-word since it's a homonym of "肏" which **means** the F-word.

If you are looking for a more speakable word, 倒霉, 该死 or 见鬼 would be more fit.

Comment: I did not put "靠" because it is actually "尻" which is even dirty as I presume. But anyway, they are almost the same to me. :P

Comment: No, it's not. It's a pure exclamation nowadays.

Comment: As I understand, the relation between 靠 and 尻 and the one between 操 and 肏 are the same. They are all 通假字. Both 靠 and 操 are used as 通假 only after computer era.

Comment: @Flake: But one never says "我尻", instead one says "我靠" or "我操". That is said, 靠 is more like a neutral replacement for 操. It can be used both good or bad way.

Comment: If I understood correctly, even though my dictionary says "_to f*ck (vulgar)_" for 靠, it's not actually a swear word but an exclamation?

Comment: @Flake: For the record, 靠 did used as a dirty-less replacement for 尻 first, but 尻 is clearly an uncivilized word for typing on the internet.

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter: That still depends on the occasion as any word. I think it will be a very bad impression if a non-native speaker speaks that way.

Comment: @Kabie: Hm, in that case I might stick with 糟糕! :)

Comment: @drHannibalLecter To me, "糟糕" seems only appear in novels and movies rather than in real life conversations. Meanwhile, the very similar things, "糟了" / "坏了", are used in the situations where one forgets something important or similar. E.g. when I forget my project report in a meeting to managers, I may say "糟了" or "坏了" or "靠" or "操" silently.

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter: Yes, 糟糕 is the word. However it usually is said softly and repeatedly, unlike a big, loud /dæm/ could frame the emotion.

Answer (score 3):

I know some people might think 干 is not-so-mild, but I tend to hear it a lot in the sense of

```
Damn, all the way over there? That's a long way to go
干！那么远的地方？走过去要很久
```

or

```
That chick is hot, damn!
那个正妹好辣，干！
```

Comment: Can you add Chinese examples?