# What does the phrase '我的妈来' mean when it is used to express shock or surprise?

Tags: translation, usage, simplified-characters, expressions, slang

I know the literal meaning, but could someone please tell me the meaning in english when it was used as an expression (for example, when someone see a huge mansion and he said: "我的妈来! What a huge castle!")? thanks

Comment: 我的妈呀! Oh, my god (mum)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"我的妈来" is a playful way to say "去[他妈的](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/150/how-offensive-is-%E4%BB%96%E5%A6%88%E7%9A%84)" in code

It is a word game require a sense of humor and little bit of wit to get the punchline.

A simpler example would be "小處不可隨便" (can't be casual even on minor details).

When people saw this phrase, it is very likely that they would think of "不可隨處小便" (Do not urinate anywhere). You just have to rearrange all the characters.

As for  "我的妈来" (my mother comes), Not only you have to rearrange all the characters to get "来我妈的"; you also have to replace '来(come)' with '去(go)'; '我(I)' with '他(he)' to get the punchline line "去他妈的"(damn it)

- [他妈的](https://translate.google.ca/#zh-CN/en/%E4%BB%96%E5%A6%88%E7%9A%84) is a vulgar exclamation similar to 'Damn it' in English
- [去你的](http://www.ichacha.net/%E5%8E%BB%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84.html) is also an exclamation
- 去他妈的 is the combination of the above two phrases

**Edit:**

Lydwinne Catherinne wrote:

> *So it is just an expression that doesn't have the exact english translation? People may read that as, for example, (sorry) "WTF" or "Holy Sh*t"?*

Yes, 他妈的 and 去你的 are exclamations. Literal meanings in exclamations are not important.

Anyway...

- "他妈的" literally means "his mother's".  But it vulgarly implies "他妈的X (His mother's X )"
- "去你的" literally means "You be gone" . Which can be understood innocently as:" get out of here!" or vulgarly implies: "去你的卵蛋(be gone your testicles)".
- (去勢) = 'to castrate'

Comment: So it is just an expression that doesn't have the exact english translation? People may read that as, for example, (sorry) "WTF" or "Holy Sh*t"?

Comment: See my edition in the answer

Comment: 我的妈 not means 他妈的

Comment: No, 我的妈来 itself is not a phrase. It  is just a word play. Because it matches 去他妈的 . Which  in the hidden second part of a couplet " 我的妈来, (去他妈的)"

Comment: I strongly disagree with this explanation. Though I haven't seen any where using this expression, from the presentation itself it cannot mean the F word. It might mean "Oh my god!" or "Jesus!".

Comment: Why do everyone down vote my answer ignoring '来' in '我的妈来?' ; '我的妈啊!' or "妈啊!" might  function as exclamation similar to "Oh my God!", but  "我的妈来" literally mean " My mother comes".

Answer (score 3):

I would say it could mean anything that could express surprise in English. eg, "Oh Mine" "Wow" etc. I don't think it means "WTF" and "Holy sht". it's just a surprise. it could be either bad thing or good thing that happens to someone. Usually, people would say "我的妈呀" or "妈呀" instead of "我的妈来" to express surprise.

Comment: Actually in many accents, such as Jianghuai Madarin, Wu lanuage, and Xiang language, 唻 is used much more common than 呀.

Comment: @HarrySummer, yeah it could be. "我的妈来" sounds a little funny to me. I could be slightly amused by hearing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

“我的妈来”更像是表示一种惊讶的语气，并不是"my mother come"，它应该被翻译成类似于"Oh My God"这样的表示惊讶的话语。
相似的还有“我的妈呀”，“我的妈”，“我的天”或者“妈呀”。
和“去他妈的”("damn it")意思不一样。